# JS multiple file input elements on page - inputs not working past first input (preview image not showing)

Tags: javascript, html, file, input

Trying to get multiple file inputs and their corresponding previews to load. I am getting elements by classname but i don't think i'm iterating over them correctly. I don't want to use unique IDs for the elements since i will be adding these to the page dynamically and can't hardcode unique IDs for each input. If you could please edit my code or tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks. Codepen below.
https://codepen.io/pfbarnet/pen/VwMgmbP

```
var fileTag = document.getElementsByClassName("filetag"), i,
    preview = document.getElementsByClassName("preview"), i;


for (i = 0; i < fileTag.length; ++i) {
    //check if fileTag null
    fileTag[0].addEventListener("change", function () {
      changeImage(this);
    });
  

  function changeImage(input) {
    var reader;

    if (input.files && input.files) {
      reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        preview[0].setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
      };
}
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    
  }
}

<input type='file' class='filetag'><img src='test' class='preview'/></input>

<input type='file' class='filetag'><img src='test' class='preview'/></input>
```

Comment: `fileTag[0]` should be `fileTag[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Few notec my friend. First you need to declare your variable `i` inside the loop with a `let` keyword, otherwise it will be global scoped.

In your loop, instead of always assigning event listener to the first element you need to make it dynamic by writing `fileTag[i]` instead of `fileTag[0]`

Also when `changeImage` is being called, also pass the `i` variable to it, so inside the body of this function, you can change exact image's src.

Take a look at the code below.

```
for (let i = 0; i < fileTag.length; ++i) { // <- Declare with a let keyword
    fileTag[i].addEventListener("change", function () {
      changeImage(this, i); // <- HERE
    });
}
```

And here, use `i` to indicate which exact element you are mutating e.g. the image and the fileInput

```
function changeImage(input, i) {
  console.log(input);
  var reader;

  if (input.files && input.files) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      preview[i].setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
    };
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
}
```